# Actuarial survival analysis, divided into intervals

Tags: r, statistics, stata, spss, survival-analysis

I'm trying to create an actuarial survival analysis in R (I'm following some worked examples). I think the best way to do this is using the `survival` package. So something like:

```
library(survival)
surv.test <- survfit(Surv(TIME,STATUS), data=test)
```

However, to get the correct answer I will need to divide the `TIME` variable into 365 day intervals and I can't quite work out how to do this so it matches the given result.

As far as I can make out, there is no option within the `survfit` function that will do this. I went through several document examples and none of them were trying to create a stairstep type of plot (there is a `type='interval'` option, but seems to do something different). So I guess I need to regroup my data before I apply the `survival` function?

Any ideas?

P.S: In SPSS this would be `INTERVAL = THRU 10000 BY 365`; in Stata `intervals(365) ... connect(stairsteps)`

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. +1 as I think this isn't an unreasonable question. How are the TIME and STATUS variables set up right now?

Comment: What would help is some kind of example that could be run and you telling us why the example is wrong and what we should change.

Comment: Who asked if I worked at BNPP? The answer is no, incidentally.

Comment: Why do you need to divide the `TIME` variable into intervals? Are you trying to plot the Kaplan-Meier curve (sometimes called a stairstep plot)? Or are you trying to add time-varying covariates to your model? It makes a big difference.

Comment: The table contains roughly 9,400 records of events and the data ought to be grouped in years (according to the exercise).

The STATUS variable is a simple 0,1 variable to depict if the person had a certain operation, while the TIME variable is days since another operation.

I'm sorry, but I can't post images yet. Imagine that in R there is a thick flat line depicted instead of wide steps that can be seen in the SPSS and STATA output.

I think the problem is that the table contains daily events and the steps are too small (TIME runs from 0 to 6249).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to divide the `TIME` variable into intervals because you want to plot a Kaplan-Meier curve. In R, that isn't necessary, you can just call plot on the `survfit` object. For example,

```
s=survfit(Surv(futime, fustat)~rx, data=ovarian)
plot(s)
```

[image]

---

I think I understand your question a little better. The reason why you are getting a thick black line is because you have a lot of censoring, and a `+` is being plotted at every single point where there is censoring, you can turn this off with `mark.time=F`. (You can see other options in `?survival:::plot.survfit`)

However, if you still want to aggregate by year, simply divide your follow up time by 365, and round up. `ceiling` is used to round up. Here is an example of aggregating at different time levels without censoring.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(survfit(Surv(ceiling(futime), fustat)~rx, data=ovarian),col=c('blue','red'),main='Day',mark.time=F)
plot(survfit(Surv(ceiling(futime/30), fustat)~rx, data=ovarian),col=c('blue','red'),main='Month',mark.time=F)
plot(survfit(Surv(ceiling(futime/365), fustat)~rx, data=ovarian),col=c('blue','red'),main='Year',mark.time=F)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

But I think that plotting the Kaplan-Meier without the censoring symbols will look very nice, and provide more insight.

[image]

Comment: As my TIME variable is in days I only get a thick black line as output when using the standard <survfit> method. The data needs to be plotted as year intervals, otherwise the steps won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray, I should be able to post the images now:

1) this is how the R basic survival plot looks like at the moment
[image]

2) and this is how it should look like (SPSS example)
[image]

Comment: It was a good idea to add the plots. However, you edit your answer, and put the plots there, and then delete this "answer".

Comment: I think the images should be added to the original question.

Comment: Couldn't add images at that time point, but will do next time.

Answer (score 0):

That was exactly what I was missing! Thanks!

[image]

**Solution:**

```
vas.surv <- survfit(Surv(ceiling(TIME/365), STATUS)~1, conf.type="none", data=vasectomy)
plot(vas.surv, ylim=c(0.975,1), mark.time=F, xlab="Years", ylab="Cumulative Survival")
```

A nice touch would be to displays the days on the x-axis instead of the years (as in SPSS) example, but I'm not too bothered about this.

Comment: Quite a few questions here on SO touch labeling axes with time components. Feel free to browse.

Comment: Bit nasty this one as it is not just relabelling (e.g. suppressing the plot of the x-axis with xaxt='n' and then reassigning labels with the axis command) of the axis, but the tick marks placement will change as well.

Comment: Specifically, take a look at `?survival:::plot.survfit` to find out more about this plot command.

Comment: But all you would have to do to rescale it is use the `xscale` parameter. So for years to days you would scale it by `xscale=1/365`

Comment: Brilliant! `?survival:::plot.survfit` is a good command to keep!